DTO for Spring Data REST repository Export
Is there a way to view DTO objects via Spring Data REST Repository Export? I mean direct access to the repository methods: http://localhost:8080/api/productObjects/doSomethingMethod?id=1

@Query("SELECT new com.example.project.dto.DTO(p.id, p.name) FROM
Product p WHERE p.id = :id") List doSomethingMethod(@Param("id")
Long id);

Spring Boot means i need PersistenceEntity for my DTO Object:
`**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 02 13:31:10 CEST 2024 There was an unexpected error
(type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Couldn't find
PersistentEntity for type class de.irahi.welp.dto.PuppyDTO
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find
PersistentEntity for type class de.irahi.welp.dto.PuppyDTO    at
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:80)
at
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:116)
at
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:86)
at
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:69)
at
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:34)
at
java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)**`

I tried other techniques like RestController and it worked, I tried ModelMapper and it worked too. Finally, I tried with interface projection and I got the next response from Spring Boot:

`**Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
/error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 02 15:14:02 CEST 2024 There was an unexpected error
(type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Couldn't find
PersistentEntity for type class jdk.proxy18.$Proxy226
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find
PersistentEntity for type class jdk.proxy18.$Proxy226     at
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:80)
a**...`

